# php - How can 3rd party access a script on my server?

Tags: php

How can 3rd party access a script on my server?

The 3rd party has a device which send updated values (may be) to their server. Now, i want to do like whenever they receive data, they should call/execute a script on my server.

For example,

```
while(1) {
    if(DATA_ARRIVED) {
        // execute or call http://example.com/update_data.php
        // to do its own function
    }
}
```

The code is just example. I have no idea what/how they receive the new data. But this is what i want to do.

Thanks a lot for help

Regards

Comment: Well, I suppose *they* could setup their server script to cURL or some other thing, calling *your* script from *their* server. In which case, you would need a script ready to accept and process what data they send. What you're asking, though, appears to be somewhat underformed and abstract.

Answer (score 1):

They can use [curl](http://php.net/curl) functions to post the data to a script on your site, [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) to manually perform the http request if curl is not available, or if it is a simple get request, [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) of your URL with parameters in the query string would work as well.

Curl would be the most common option, and is reliable and easy to use.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it. You can set up a REST API for the third party to post data to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be executed on 3rd party side, use [remote incude](http://php.net/include): `include 'http://www.example.com/file.php';`

If you want it to be executed on your side, just open your page from 3rd party side with [curl](http://php.net/curl) or fopen: `$file = fopen("http://www.example.com/file.php", "r");`